# Can't type "o" in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to do some programming but I can't use "o".

Here is the issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hShR.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEhvj.png

This happens every time I press any keys but I can't use "o".

Can someone please help?

Comment: Maybe you need to reset key binding. You can view how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51232593/11487196)

Answer (score 0):

1. Press ctrl+k+s
2. You will see keyboard shortcuts
3. In the search bar paste two zeros.
4. You will see a keyboard shortcut.
5. Click that and delete that keyblind
6. Problem solved.